# How to set priority of neighboring Triggers in XAML (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate

There are few Triggers/MultiTriggers affecting the same Property of the same Target in the same ControlTemplate. What defines the priority between them in case of simultaneous activation of all?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

   <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"> <!-- #1 -->
       <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
   </Trigger>

   <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True"> <!-- #2 -->
       <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Orange"/>
   </Trigger>

</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

In my example, I have ControlTemplate for the ProgressBar, where I set two triggers for my custom "background" element. If the ProgressBar gets both disabled & indeterminate, I have the effect of the #2 trigger, making it Orange, while I want to make it #1 Gray in such case.

Comment: To be sure of what is going on you should really use MultiTrigger https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.multitrigger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 and define the behavior when (IsEnabled=false, IsIndeterminate=true), (IsEnabled=true, IsIndeterminate=true) (IsEnabled=false, IsIndeterminate=false),...

Comment: @NPE Thank you, but that can be useful in a very limited way. Moreover, the post question is actual for few neighboring MultiTriggers as well.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your comment. Why is it useful in a limited way ? Your specification is be gray when disabled & indeterminate so <MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
      <Condition Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
  </MultiTrigger>

Comment: @NPE This is a comfortable solution for handling a few-conditional behavior. But, the number of MultiTriggers will grow exponentially having more conditions, so it would be nice to know if their priority is manageable or at least predictable.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such thing as priority. You activate a Trigger whenever the attached property (ies) is changed. So no need for sense of priority it just reacts on the change of property (In your case IsIndeterminate becomes True so Fill becomes orange regardless of the value of IsEnabled). As for dealing with combinatorial It should rarely happen to have more than three  (so at most 8combinaisons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All triggers are evaluated from top to bottom.
In pseudo code this translates to

```
if (IsEnabled == false) { background.Fill = Gray }
if (isIndeterminate == true) { background.Fill = Orange }
```

So, if you want to achieve the desired result, simply swap them to be

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True"> <!-- #2 -->
    <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Orange"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"> <!-- #1 -->
    <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
</Trigger>
```

To further answer your earlier question, if for example, we did

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True"> <!-- #2 -->
    <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter TargetName="forground" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"> <!-- #1 -->
    <Setter TargetName="background" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
</Trigger>
```

If IsInderminate is true AND IsEnabled is false, then the background will be gray and the foreground will be red because the triggers are evaluated and the setters are applied from top to bottom. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried swapping at first, but somehow it didn't work out. Though it actually works, having the clear rule of precedence in mind. Thank you!